# Should I Use HTML Server-Side Includes?

Tags: html, nginx, ssi

We've recently migrated from a full CMS to simple HTML/CSS/JS on NGINX. I do batch editing with RegEx search/replace in my text editor, but I'd like to simplify by putting common content in partial files and including them server-side. I've considered other solutions, but I'm working under some constraints:

- It's important to us to have the site function whether javascript is present or not, so I prefer not to use client-side frameworks for including content.
- I personally prefer compiled, templated solutions like Jekyll or Pug (Jade), but I have a pretty non-technical team I'm trying to support, and HTML is already a bit beyond their comfort level.

My problem is that I haven't found any up-to-date information about using SSI. (Most pages returned from web search look like they were built 20 years ago). The fact that no one seems to be talking about SSI in a modern context has me a little worried.

**Are HTML server-side includes a reasonable solution for this situation? If  so, are there performance or security issues I should watch out for?**

Comment: Why don't you use Jekyll includes?

Comment: @JoostS We're just developing straight HTML rather than implemening a build system like Jekyll. I've got a pretty non-technical team I'm trying to support.

Answer (score 2):

Well security is not an issue if you ask me. These are just server side includes, and not user input. The performance is far from great, if you believe [this](https://www.passmark.com/forum/general/2160-ssi-vs-php-includes-benchmarks). However, horsepower is cheap, and so is caching. It seems okay to me to use it.